# propagete values from parent to child

Tags: trigger

I have created two objects i.e Parent and Child And Added fields to it,now I want to add trigger such that address of parent is fired to child address.

Explain it step wise so it become clear how triggers will be used.And all the relationship which i have to use.

Comment: Any reason why the address fields on the child can not be formula fields getting the information from the parent fields ?

Comment: If you do need a trigger for some reason be very careful about running into limits if you have many, many child records.

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost I strongly recommends you to read some of the [official doc](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers.htm) and the [best practices](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Apex_Code_Best_Practices)

Then, this is a brief guide:

1. Create a Trigger on parent after insert/update
2. Then recover child records in a list/map (you have to consider make your trigger bulk-safe)
3. Update the address fields
4. Update the list of childs

This is an small an trivial sample of the idea:

```
trigger copyParentToChild on Parent__c (before insert, before update) {

    //recover childs
    Child__c[] childrens = [Select Parent__c, Street__c from Child__c where Parent__c in :Trigger.new ];
    for(Child__c c :childrens){
        c.Street__c = Trigger.newMap.get(c.Parent__c).Street__c;
        //the rest of the fields here
    }
    update childrens;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be good solution for you:

```
trigger propagateParentValues on Parent__c (After Insert, After Update) {

   Child__c[] recordsToupdate = new Child__c[]{};

   for(Parent__c parent : [SELECT /** required fields from parent**/
                           (SELECT  /** required fields from child**/
                            FROM Childs__r)
                     FROM Parent__c 
                     WHERE Id IN :Trigger.new ]){
       for(Child__c c : parent.Childs__r){
          if(parent.valueFromParent != c.valueFromChildren ){
              c.valueFromChildren = parent.valueFromParent;
              recordsToupdate.add(c);

          }
       }
    }
    if(!recordsToupdate.isEmpty()){
        update recordsToupdates;
    }
   }
```

Comment: trigger aopyPhone2contacts on Account (After Insert, After Update) {

   Contact[] recordsToupdate = new Contact[]{};

   for(Account acc: [SELECT Id, AccountPhone__c,
                           (SELECT Phone, Id FROM Contact)
                     FROM Account
                     WHERE Id IN :Trigger.new ]){
       for(Contact c : acc.Contact){
          if(acc.AccountPhone__c!= c.Phone){
              c.Phone= parent.AccountPhone__c;
              recordsToupdate.add(c);
          }
       }
    }
    if(!recordsToupdate.isEmpty()){
        update recordsToupdates;
    }
   }

Comment: I tried to copy AccountPhone custom field to contact phone field...  using your above code, but failed @artur

Comment: It looks Ok... Did you tried debug it?

Comment: How should I approach debugging?

Comment: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_debugging_debug_log.htm